# I cannot add items in an array using the setTimeout function

Tags: angularjs

I'm trying to update the ui by pushing a new entry into an array but for some reason the ui is not updated until the next operation on the array.

```
function TestCtrl($scope){
  $scope.projects = [{name: "project1"}];

  $scope.test = function(){ return "batman"; };

  $scope.addNew = function(){
    $scope.projects.push({name: "project2"});
    setTimeout(function(){
      $scope.projects.push({name: "project3"});
    }, 1000);
  };
}
```

And here is an example http://jsbin.com/itasis/4/edit

I didn't tested yet but I expect the same issue in behavior from an ajax request.

Comment: Use [$timeout](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.$timeout) instead of `setTimeout`.  `$timeout` will automatically call `$apply()` for you, triggering an Angular digest cycle, causing your view to update.

Comment: Regarding AJAX, that depends how you are using it.  If you use $http, it will also automatically call `$apply()` for you.

Comment: I'm thinking of using the jquery ajax function. Is there incompatibility between the libraries ? How should I trigger the $apply function in case of using the jquery ajax.

Comment: You should use $http if you can.  There are no incompatibilities -- jQuery works fine alongside Angular (if you need it).  If you want to use jQuery AJAX, then inside your AJAX handler, after you update your Angular models/scope, call `scope.$apply()`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use [$timeout](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.%24timeout) instead of `setTimeout`.  `$timeout` automatically calls `$apply()` for us, triggering an [Angular digest cycle](http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/concepts#runtime), which will update any views that need to be refreshed.

Regarding AJAX, I would encourage you to use Angular's [$http](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.%24http) service, which will also call `$apply()` for us.  Otherwise, in your AJAX callback, after updating your Angular models/scope, manually call `scope.$apply()`.